# Is there some kind of equivalent to .NET's BackgroundWorker in Vala?

Tags: linux, multithreading, gtk, vala

I'm trying to learn Vala so I'm making a small GUI application. My main language before has been C# so things are going pretty well.

However, I've hit the wall now. I need to connect to an external network server (using GIO) which doesn't answer my client immediately. This makes the GUI freeze up while the program is connecting and doing its thing.

In C# I would probably use a BackgroundWorker in this case. I can't seem to find anything like it for Vala though.

Basically, I have a MainWindow.vala where I have hooked up a signal for clicking a certain button to a method that is creating a new instance of ProcessingDialog.vala. This shows a dialog over the MainWindow that I want the user to see while the program is doing the work (connecting to the server, communicating).

What are my alternatives to make this scenario work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIO offers async methods, see an async client for example: https://live.gnome.org/Vala/GIONetworkingSample

If you are not aware of async methods in Vala, try looking at the tutorial: https://live.gnome.org/Vala/Tutorial#Asynchronous_Methods

Answer (score 0):

lethalman's answer above probably makes the most sense, an async request is really going to be your best bet if you're doing a network call. In other cases, you can use Vala's built in [thread support](http://live.gnome.org/Vala/ThreadingSamples) to accomplish a background task. It looks like soon enough, there will be a better library available, but this is what's stable.

```
// Create the function to perform the task
public void thread_function() {
    stdout.printf("I am doing something!\n");
}

public int main( string[] args ) {
    // Create the thread to start that function
    unowned Thread<void*> my_thread = Thread.create<void*>(thread_function, true);

    // Some time toward the end of your application, reclaim the thread
    my_thread.join();

    return 1;
}
```

Remember to compile with the "--thread" option.